# Beginner in Blender

Tags: modeling, armature, interface

So, I just got blender and I don't know what I'm doing. How to get started with blender? Tutorials to watch and whatnot, somebody help me please I don't want to be groping about in the dark I need somebody to point me in the right direction

Comment: Hello and welcome. I would advise you to start with the tutorials available on the Blender website, which you can also find on their Youtube channel here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kes2qmijy7w&list=PLa1F2ddGya_8V90Kd5eC5PeBjySbXWGK1

Comment: you have a lot of tutorials on youtube, just type "blender tutorial beginner" or something like that

Comment: The question is too broad and can only get primarily opinion based answers. It is not ideal for this platform. I think you will get better general advice on forums like Blenderartists.org. The question will most likely get closed eventually, but don't take this the wrong way. You should ask all the more specific questions that you encounter during your learning process. It's a good place to get good detailed answers for more specific things quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool thing with Blender is that it's used for many things from ocean simulations to making video game assets, the big thing I found with people is when they open it they are like super confused with the amount of buttons to press just know a lot of it you wont need if you're specializing and if not there is this cool "cheat sheet" which will be linked first.

1. https://www.giudansky.com/downloads/learnwithaposter/blender-poster-infographic/blender-infographic-SM-1280.png
   This is for whole Blender now if you can have it printed and set on the side while you're working.
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLV7h-WLIx0
   This explains most of the UI and it's settings.
   When you get that sorted out start with
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VT5oZndzj68&list=PLjEaoINr3zgHs8uzT3yqe4iHGfkCmMJ0P
   This is a whole playlist from Blender Guru covering everything, from UI to Lighting and should get you to speed with the software when you're finished you should be covered on most things and then you can decide if and where you want to specialize.